# How to clean up Windows 10 machine after failed attempt at Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot

I have a new Windows 10 laptop, on which I attempted to install Ubuntu 17.04 for dual boot. As part of the "install alongside Windows" installation, Ubuntu offered a screen that allows allocation of drive space by dragging a divider, and I gave most space to Ubuntu.

Installation seemed successful but I can't boot into Ubuntu -it always goes directly to Windows (perhaps because I omitted to disable Fast Startup before install). So now if I go to Disk Management in Windows I have an unused but large partition:

[image]

Long story short, I think best to abandon trying to install/boot Ubuntu (prob too complicated for me), and so I chose the Delete Volume option on the 158GB volume, and now have:

[image]

I'm hoping that using the Extend Volume Wizard on C: will give the 158GB back to Windows.

Assuming I can complete that, will it be as if I never tried installing Ubuntu, or should I do other cleanup?

Comment: Why don't you just format the partition to NTFS? There's nothing wrong just leaving it the way it is right now; Windows and system files on one partition and another one where you'll install all your apps and store your personal files/data.

Comment: Extending the volume is all you have to do here. But I wonder why you give up on linux that easily? You could btw. install Linux in a virtual machine e.g. with VirtualBox as a safe alternative.

Comment: Cool, I'll give that a try. It's just all this UEFI/dual booting stuff scares me

Comment: This is what you need to know and understand: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI . Then learn about partitions and requirements for dual booting. If you need further help consider posting at [askubuntu.se] although this should cover all the possible scenarios: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: @MichaelBay thanks, but VirtualBox seems to give me Ubuntu 17 in full screen with very straightforward setup -just used most defaults -easier on my brain that dual boot. TBH now I'm just concerned with making sure I've cleaned up after failed attempt at dual boot

Comment: There's nothing particularly challenging in a dual boot compared with installing standalone OSes and UEFI makes it even easier than before. If you don't want to become "obsolete" you better learn about UEFI ASAP, irrespective of dual or standalone installation. Using Ubuntu in a VM does not teach you anything useful (in this regard) and is much slower and limited than a real installation.

Comment: @MichaelBay Ah ok. There seems to be a lot of things that can trip up dual boot installation with UEFI, whereas under BIOS it would always just work, but I will try again at some point. Have to find out how to install it to my deleted volume.

Comment: I think the step you were missing was adding Ubuntu to the MS bootloader: https://neosmart.net/wiki/bcdedit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small complication in your case, that for an unknown reason,
the Ubuntu installer has reduced the Windows partition and moved it to the
end of the disk, establishing its own before that.
This will force you to move back up the Windows partition before extending
it, but I would counsel to keep the existing partition numbers.

I suggest the following procedure :

1. Backup all your files, Windows serial number, as well as all media
   required for reinstalling your products and drivers, just in case.
2. Install backup product, for example
   [AOMEI Backupper Standard Free](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html),
   and backup the entire disk to external media.
   Create the AOMEI boot CD or USB, and boot it as a test whether it can see
   both your disk and the disk where the image backup is stored.
   This will ensure that you can go back in case of error without the need
   to reinstall everything.
3. Delete the Ubuntu partition from inside Windows (to ensure no errors,
   as Disk Manager will not let you destroy Windows).
   Replace it with a small dummy partition whose only purpose will be to
   conserve the partition number of Windows.
   The order of partitions will then be : EFI, Recovery, dummy,
   unallocated space, Windows.
   There is a small chance that Windows will become unbootable after this step,
   so prepare the software for the step 4 before starting this step.
4. Boot with a partition editor CD or USB, for example
   [AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition Free](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-partition.html),
   and move the Windows partition up, so it follows the dummy partition
   created in step 2.
   This will in effect move the unallocated space to after it.
5. Boot into Windows and resize its partition to include the unallocated space.
6. Optionally, delete the boot code installed for Ubuntu.
   I would first take another image backup of the entire disk.
   You can use
   [Visual BCD Editor](https://www.boyans.net/) for the deletion,
   as explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/539620).

Comment: Thanks for all the detail. I've updated the post to show the current state of things according to the Disk Management tool -perhaps C: is still at start of disk?

Comment: In the "install alongside Windows" installation, Ubuntu offered a screen that allowed allocation of drive space by dragging a divider -I gave most space to Ubuntu.

Comment: You currently have 158GB of unallocated space between Recovery and Windows (the layout is at the bottom of the image). If Windows is still bootable then Windows 10 does not need the dummy partition, so you may continue with step 4, moving up the Windows partition to immediately follow the Recovery partition. Although the partition editor can resize the Windows partition, resist temptation and do it via Windows. I just hope you have backups, because partition work is always dangerous.

Comment: Windows 10 does boot so I'll skip to step 4. Have backups :) Sorry -so moving the partition and resizing it are different things?

Comment: Yes - two different actions. Resize it in Windows since it won't let you destroy anything, Windows cannot move its own system partition, so you have to do that first from a boot CD/USB.

Comment: Ah right. Why do I need to move the partition, as opposed to jumping straight to step 5?

Comment: You can't increase the partition to go beyond the end of the disk. To increase its size, the unallocated space must *follow* the Windows partition, but it currently *precedes* it.

Comment: Sorry to be a dunce but doesn't the diagram show C: before the unallocated space? Perhaps I'm wrong to "read" it left to right

Comment: No problem - this is new for you. You can see  the disk layout at the bottom. Try to resize the Windows partition and see - this is harmless as Windows will not let you do anything harmful.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm hoping that using the Extend Volume Wizard on C: will give the 158GB back to Windows.
>
> Assuming I can complete that, will it be as if I never tried installing Ubuntu, or should I do other cleanup?

In my experience if you extend drive C:, then you'll get back the 158GB, if it is labeled as unallocated. I think, the Grub bootloader will still stay on the master boot record after that; but here I'm not that experienced at UEFI and it works bit different I think. If you want to clean this, somebody different should help :)

**Dual Boot**
After installation of Ubuntu, did you try to change the boot manager in the BIOS? On my Laptop with Win10/Linux Mint it looks like that:
[image: UEFI Boot Order in BIOS]

After your  installation, did you change the UEFI Boot Order to "ubuntu ..."? If you do change that to "ubuntu ...", then you'll get the GRUB boot menu at startup and you could choose between Win10 and Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I don't see a UEFI Boot Order option.

Comment: do you have another boot order option? Somewhere you must have a menu where you can set the boot order.

Comment: I can hit F12 when booting, but the only option displayed is Windows Boot Manager. When hitting F2 I can set boot order but the listed items are Windows Boot Manager, CD drive, USB etc. -nothing that looks like Ubuntu